# Static class object

Tags: c++

Why are static class objects allowed in C++? what is their use?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
  static Test self;  // works fine

  /* other stuff in class*/

};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just works; the compiler doesn't have to do anything special simply because `self` is both a static member of `Test` and is of type `Test`. I see no reason why this special case would need to be specifically prohibited.

Now, there *is* a problem with `Test::self` in that you declare the variable, but fail to define it. However, this is simply a bug in your code and is easily fixed:

```
class Test {
  ...
};

Test Test::self; // <--- the definition

int main()
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You use it for things that are shared between all instances of the class. For example, you can use it to implement the [Singleton pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1921/Singleton-Pattern-its-implementation-with-C).